# Question on Division of Infinite Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

I am wondering if it is possible to evaluate the following expression:

$\frac{\int^{\infty}_{0} dx}{\int^{\infty}_{0} dx}$

Here are my uninformed and somewhat scattered thoughts on the question:

Let $a$ be equal the numerator and $b$ the denominator. Then $a = \int^{\infty}_{0} dx$ and $b = \int^{\infty}_{0} dx$ so $a = b$. Then the expression simplifies to $\frac{a}{a} = 1$.

I'm not sure if writing $\frac{a}{a}$ is a mistake as they are both infinite. If I take the limit I have:

$\lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{a}{a} = 1$

If the expression with the limit is legal, why isn't the expression without the limit allowed? And if I do have an expression like $\frac{a}{a}$ can I just say that $\frac{a}{a} = \lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{a}{a} = 1$?

Comment: Dividing a quantity by itself should always give you 1 if the division makes sense. You could think of defining $a(x)=\int_0^x dt$ and then noting that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a(x)}{a(x)}=1$. Conceptually $\frac{a_{\infty}}{a_{\infty}}$ does not make sense unless you see it as the limit at infinity of the identically $1$ function. This is how one usually deals with indeterminate expressions. Not sure if this helps with your intuition.

Answer (score 1):

When we write $\int_a^\infty g(t)dt$, what this means by definition is $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^b g(t)dt$. So I would interpret your expression as
$$\frac{\int_0^\infty dx}{\int_0^\infty dx} = \frac{\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^b dx}{\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^b dx} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$$
which is an indeterminate form.

If you insisted on assigning a meaningful expression to it, the most natural would seem to be $1$, but this kind of justification comes from the idea of taking one limit instead of two. It's sort of like asking, is $\frac{\sin(0)}{0} = 1$? Well, if it is taken as the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ then yes, but if you instead take the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(vx)}{x}$ then the answer is $v$. Hence, that $\frac{\sin(0)}{0}$ is indeterminate, much like what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be rigorous, you would note that $$\frac{\int_0^{\infty}\,\mathrm{d}x}{\int_0^{\infty}\,\mathrm{d}x}$$ is actually a shorthand for $$\lim_{a\to\infty,\;b\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^a\,\mathrm{d}x}{\int_0^b\,\mathrm{d}x}=\lim_{a\to\infty,\;b\to\infty}\frac{a}{b},$$ and this limit does not exist.